# Data recovery software recovered folder as .exe

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

The exe has exact same size and name as the original folder so Im sure data is intact.

Ive searched about this problem but all results were about a virus hiding folder and making a new malicious .exe look as the original folder.

My case is different because **the .exe actually is the folder and the folder is recovered by Testdisk as an .exe file.**

Comment: @EVERYONE please see the whole issue here maybe it will help solve the issue. http://superuser.com/questions/738668/testdisk-versus-corrupted-removable-sdcard-and-phone-storage

Answer (score 0):

Generally good behaving recovery software would not do such a thing. Also if it indeed was your actual folder it would open as such—you can name a folder `folder.exe` it will still be a folder and not executable, if it is executable though it is definitely some kind of trickery from malware/virus camp.

Comment: thanks very much for answer but it certainly isnt virus.I guess that the bytes describing file type got somehow corrupted.I just want to somehow either access the files with some program to copy them or convert the exe to folder.

Comment: Folder is not a file per se it is a record in the filesystem index. Alternative to virus could be self-extracting archive generated by your recovery program, which is unlikely and if true must be mentioned in the recovery software documentation or specified in its configuration.

Comment: Im very confused :'( It is most certainly a folder.I checked again several times (using old image of my monitor screen)and it IS a folder.The image shows me the exact same filename and size of file.But now somehow it is an exe

Comment: please see the whole issue here maybe it will help solve the issue. http://superuser.com/questions/738668/testdisk-versus-corrupted-removable-sdcard-and-phone-storage

Comment: I only have one suggestion—try other recovery software (as many of them as you care), they all have different algorithms and excel in different things so by trying as many of them as you can you'll achieve better results. Unfortunately though most of the time you won't be able to recover everything even when you stopped using the device immediately after you lost something.

Comment: Thanks very much, please see link above maybe it will help?

Comment: My previous comment was actually based on the link you provided :)