# Testdisk VersuS corrupted removable sdcard and phone storage

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, testdisk

I've tried most of things for my very specific situation in Testdisk but they didn't help except a few things I havent tried because I dont know if and how do them.

*What happened:*

I had removable sdcard in phone and plugged phone into Pc via usb cable to charge phone and reverse tether (share PC's internet connection with phone).
The storages are always automounted even if I havent used Mount USB Storage in Android. For some reason (I don't know why) I used the option. After that I used unmount usb storage and pulled cable because it was taking very long and I thought that it is safe because the storage is not doing anything.

I also only selected eject removable media for one storage only (I use Lubuntu 14.04 Linux Operating System)

*What is now:*

Most of the files are gone and the storages have more free space. I've not used the phone at all yet (for two weeks) to not overwrite any file. I need to use phone for work but asking around on multitude of forums have not helped me yet.

#### Phone storage

In the Boot menu I get the following warnings:

```
 Disk /dev/sdb - 12 GB / 11 GiB - CHS 1502 255 63
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
   P FAT32                    0   0  1  1502  63 33   24133632 [NO NAME]

Boot sector
check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf0!=0xf8)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 4 (FAT) != 255 (HD)
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 16 (FAT) != 63 (HD)
OK

Backup boot sector
check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf0!=0xf8)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 4 (FAT) != 255 (HD)
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 16 (FAT) != 63 (HD)
OK

Sectors are identical.

A valid FAT Boot sector must be present in order to access
any data; even if the partition is not bootable.[/code]
```

*After choosing Rebuild BS (Bootsector) I get warnings:*

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 12 GB / 11 GiB - CHS 1502 255 63
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
   P FAT32                    0   0  1  1502  63 33   24133632 [NO NAME]

FAT : 32
cluster_size 64 64
reserved     32 32
total_sect   24133632 24133632
fat32_length 2946 2946
root_cluster 2 2
free_count   uninitialised 375052
next_free    uninitialised 514
Extrapolated boot sector and current boot sector are different.
```

*After the repair boot sector is finished nothing changes: I can still copy the same amount of files as before (almost nothing)*

#### Removable sdcard

```
    Disk /dev/sdc - 15 GB / 14 GiB - CHS 1909 255 63
      Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
    P FAT32                    0   0  1  1909  43 54   30670848 [NO NAME]

Boot sector
OK

Backup boot sector
OK

First sectors (Boot code and partition information) are not identical.

A valid FAT Boot sector must be present in order to access
any data; even if the partition is not bootable.
```

*After choosing Rebuild BS (Bootsector) I get warnings:*

```
 Disk /dev/sdc - 15 GB / 14 GiB - CHS 1909 255 63
   Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
 P FAT32                    0   0  1  1909  43 54   30670848 [NO NAME]

FAT : 32
cluster_size 64 64
reserved     704 704
total_sect   30670848 30670848
fat32_length 3744 3744
root_cluster 2 2
free_count   uninitialised 448822
next_free    uninitialised 11
Extrapolated boot sector and current boot sector are different.
```

#### Failed copy file attempts:

When using copy, all files that: Testdisk says are 32768 in size (there are lots of these files and they are not 32768 in size) fail to be copied and Testdisk *immediately* says 
`Copy done! 0 ok, 0 failed`. Several other files are 0 in size according to Testdisk and I get the same message.

When I select `copy 123Folder` Testdisk always copies the 123Folder but with the contents of all files it sees. (For example the copied 123Folder will contain empty 123Folder and all other files Testdisk sees on storage) This issue is for some other folders too which have 0 in size according to Testdisk

Copied folder has exact same size and filename but it is an .exe so I can't access it.

Music folder (contains .flac) and TitaniumBackup is zero in size according to Testdisk so I tried Photorec. But all files except 4 flac are corrupt.

Comment: The partition table type is None according to Testdisk (no other type shows me any partition)

Comment: Have you tried using any other recovery software? I highly recommend `dd` if on Linux or `Recuva` on Windows.

Comment: @Garrett Recuva doesnt know about flac files,And it generally was a failure.I cant make an disk image because I dont have enough gigabytes.Can I somehow make dd (or an alternative) make the image directly onto cloud storage?

Comment: Recuva can be set to recover all file types, not just those it explicitly defines. As for dd, there is no way to send the image directly to the cloud, but perhaps you could move other stuff to the cloud to create enough local storage space?

Comment: @Garrett I only have about 0.5GB of my data the rest is Lubuntu and every day it takes about 300MB more space.I reinstalled Lubuntu to have more free space because I run out of it after few weeks because L:ubuntu needs 300MB more each day.Now I have about 7.5GB free and I need at least about 13GB preferably 28GB